# Update node js packages on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

How can I tell Heroku to update my node modules?

I tried to do

```
heroku run bash
npm update <package>
```

and then restarted my heroku app

```
heroku restart -a <appname>
```

But I can't see the changes, I inserted same commands locally and it worked. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

try to :

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

`git commit -am 'rebuild' --allow-empty`

`git push heroku master`